# Testing DynamoDB: "Unable to load region from system settings"

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, unit-testing, amazon-dynamodb

I have a unit test that does nothing more than check if a bean exists.

```
    application.run( ( context ) -> {
        assertThat( context ).hasSingleBean( DynamoDbAsyncClient.class );
    } );
```

The code that creates the bean does the following:

```
@Bean
public DynamoDbAsyncClient dynamoDbAsyncClient()
{
    return DynamoDbAsyncClient.create();
}
```

This code cannot be changed!

If I run this test I get the following error:
`Unable to load region from system settings`

So how can I specify a region for DynamoDB use? Can I mock some class for instance?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like when you call [DynamoDbAsyncClient.create()](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/dynamodb/DynamoDbAsyncClient.html#create--), the [DynamoDbAsyncClient](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/dynamodb/DynamoDbAsyncClient.html) class loads the region from your [DefaultAwsRegionProviderChain](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/regions/providers/DefaultAwsRegionProviderChain.html), which appears to be using your [SystemSettingsRegionProvider](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/regions/providers/SystemSettingsRegionProvider.html) to get it from your environment variables.

I'm pretty sure the error it's giving you is on line 37 of software.amazon.awssdk.regions.providers.SystemSettingsRegionProvider, which says:

```
return SdkClientException
    .builder()
    .message(
        String.format(
            "Unable to load region from system settings. Region" + " must be 
            specified either via environment variable (%s) or " + " system 
            property (%s).", 
            SdkSystemSetting.AWS_REGION.environmentVariable(), 
            SdkSystemSetting.AWS_REGION.property()
        )
    )
    .build();
```

So to answer your question:

> So how can I specify a region for DynamoDB use? Can I mock some class for instance?

Yes, exactly: you mock the environment variable for AWS_REGION.

The easiest way to do this would be to use the library [System Lambda](https://github.com/stefanbirkner/system-lambda/), which has a method `withEnvironmentVariables` for setting environment variables.

You can use this analogously to the following:

```
import static com.github.stefanbirkner.systemlambda.SystemLambda.*;

public void EnvironmentVariablesTest {
  @Test
  public void setEnvironmentVariable() {
    String value = withEnvironmentVariable("name", "value")
      .execute(() -> System.getenv("name"));
    assertEquals("value", value);
  }
}
```

Hope that helps!